# VueJS - how to evaluate curly braces syntax from a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a component which accepts a property which contains curly braces syntax to be interpolated later inside the component.

How can I achieve such thing? Is there a function that I need to call to evaluate the curly braces syntax?

Here is my code

```
<my-component template="Hello {{ firstname }}"></my-component>
```

And this is my component

```
props: {
    template: null
},
data: function() {
    return {
        firstname: 'John',
        lastname: 'Smith'
    }
},
template: `<div>
    My message: <span>{{ template }}</span>
  </div>
`
```

The result I got

```
My message: Hello {{ firstname }}
```

What I'm expecting is

```
My message: Hello John
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xg3464b4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that the data is part of the child component, you can use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'my-component': {
            data: function() {
                return {
                    firstname: 'John',
                    lastname: 'Smith'
                }
            },
            template: `
                <div>
                    My message: <span><slot :firstname="firstname"></slot></span>
                </div>
            `
        }
    }
});
```

And the template

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component>
    <template scope="{firstname}">
        Hello {{firstname}}
    </template>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

Your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2po4v33/2/).

Comment: @AdrianGunawan Are you sure you want the data as part of your component? Typically you will pass data into the component.

Comment: yes I'd like the data to be part of the component because I want it be isolated in a component rather than part of the global Vue app.

Comment: @AdrianGunawan Updated.

Comment: thanks a lot, that works! Your solution makes me to think differently when communicating down to the child.